# Order by same as where in condtion

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i order records same as `where I.ItemCode in ()` sequence

**(sort by order of values in a select statement in clause)**

**Query**

```
SELECT I.ItemCode,I.ItemName,UM.Name As Unit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rs.RestaurantID=1 THEN RD.Quantity ELSE Null END) [res1],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rs.RestaurantID=2 THEN RD.Quantity ELSE Null END) [res2],

       SUM(RD.Quantity)TOTAL_QTY
FROM DBO.ITEMS I
LEFT JOIN UnitMeasure UM
ON I.UnitMeasureID=UM.UnitMeasureID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.RequisitionDetails RD
ON I.ItemID=RD.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Requisitions R
ON RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID
LEFT JOIN Restaurants Rs
ON R.RestaurantID=Rs.RestaurantID


where I.ItemCode in (355,365,360,275,335,350,395,320,310,340,345,305,325,315,388,300,383,385,250,245,453,326,366,368,375) and r.RequisitionDate='2016-09-23'


GROUP BY I.ItemCode,I.ItemName,UM.Name
```

Comment: Try ORDER BY I.ItemCode ASC/DESC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly hard code the ordering in `Order by` no other way

```
Order by Case ItemCode  when 355 then 0 
                        when 365 then 1 
                        when 360 then 2 
                        when 275 then 3
                        ..
                        when 368 then 24 
                        when 375 then 25 end asc
```

Each time you may have to build the `Order by` based on `IN` clause

Comment: @AT-2016 - Thanks bud

Answer (score 1):

You could also define a `CTE` with your `ItemCodes` and their order, then `JOIN` the `CTE` to your existing query. This will enable you to both filter rows on `ItemCode` and order rows on the sequence you want:

```
WITH ItemCodes AS (
    SELECT 0 AS [Order], 355 AS ItemCode UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [Order], 365 AS ItemCode UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS [Order], 360 AS ItemCode
)

SELECT I.ItemCode,I.ItemName,UM.Name As Unit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rs.RestaurantID=1 THEN RD.Quantity ELSE Null END) [res1],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Rs.RestaurantID=2 THEN RD.Quantity ELSE Null END) [res2],

       SUM(RD.Quantity)TOTAL_QTY
FROM DBO.ITEMS I
JOIN ItemCodes 
ON I.ItemCode = ItemCodes.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN UnitMeasure UM
ON I.UnitMeasureID=UM.UnitMeasureID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.RequisitionDetails RD
ON I.ItemID=RD.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Requisitions R
ON RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID
LEFT JOIN Restaurants Rs
ON R.RestaurantID=Rs.RestaurantID


where r.RequisitionDate='2016-09-23'


GROUP BY I.ItemCode,I.ItemName,UM.Name

ORDER BY ItemCodes.[Order]
```